# Estout Package in R Giving Error with IV Regression Output

Tags: r, regression

I am attempting to use the estout package to format regression tables for a LaTeX document. These are working fine for my OLS regressions, however when trying to make tables using ivreg(), I encounter the following error: `Error in esttab() : object 'adds' not found`

Here is what my code looks like:

```
fit.IV1 <- ivreg(deflatedtotalsalary ~ earlyentrypolicy + draft_year + pick + G + MP + TRB + AST 
            + PTS + STL + BLK + PER + WS | draftpolicyregime + draft_year + pick + G + MP + TRB + AST 
            + PTS + STL + BLK + PER + WS, data = mydata)

estclear()
eststo(fit.IV1) # Store model coefficients for table.

fit.IV2 <- ivreg(undeflatedtotalsalary ~ earlyentrypolicy + pick + draftage + G + MP + TRB + AST 
             + PTS + STL + BLK + PER + WS | pick + draftage + G + MP + TRB + AST 
             + PTS + STL + BLK + PER + WS + draftpolicyregime, data = mydata)

eststo(fit.IV2) # Store model coefficients for table.
esttab()
```

And, as mentioned, I get the error shown above. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the estout package may not be able to handle objects of type ivreg (for that matter, neither can xtable).

However, there appear to be a number of packages which will do the job. The easiest of which, for me, seems to be package stargazer.